# Angular Template: How to bind RXJS Observable and read its properties?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs, observable

I have created this interface:

```
interface IGame {
    name: string;
    description: string;
}
```

I'm using it as an Observable and passing it as `Input` to the `Component`:

```
@Input() public game: Observable<IGame>;
```

I can see its value printed using the JSON pipe:

```
 <h3>{{game | json}}</h3>
```

When binding to a specific property, nothing is displayed (just an empty string):

```
 <h3>{{game.name}}</h3>
 <h3>{{game.description}}</h3>
```

Answer (score 85):

The `async` pipe does the subscription in view bindings

```ts
 <h3>{{(game | async)?.name}}</h3>
```

The `?` is only necessary when `null` values might be emitted.

Answer (score 23):

### Shortcut for binding multiple properties

Using the ***ngIf-As-Syntax** factors out the `async` pipe into a single call (and a single subscription).

```
  <ng-container *ngIf="( game$ | async ) as game">
    <h3>{{ game.name }}</h3>
    <h3>{{ game.description }}</h3>
  </ng-container>
```

This only creates one subscription to the observable, it removes the need for **`?.`** and makes working with the template much cleaner.

*Note: I renamed the original example observable from `game` to `game$`.*

Comment: This answer provides slightly better user experience than the other one as it renders `<h3>{{ game.name }}</h3>` and `<h3>{{ game.description }}</h3>` at the same time.

Comment: hmm... i was thinking about your comment... it does render both fields at the same time - but if game$ is false it doesn't render anything at all - while the above example still renders the empty html-elements... So it differs - maybe causing problems when you maybe use a marker on these elements

Answer (score 5):

### The modern solution: *ngrxLet

NgRx 10 presented the `@ngrx/component` package with the **[*ngrxLet](https://ngrx.io/guide/component/let)** directive - a convenient way to bind observables in templates.

Usage example:

```
<ng-container *ngrxLet="observableNumber$ as n">
    <app-number [number]="n"></app-number>
</ng-container>
```

You can even track all the observable notifications:

```
<ng-container *ngrxLet="observableNumber$; let n; let e = $error, let c = $complete">
    ....
</ng-container>
```

[From the NgRx docs:](https://ngrx.io/guide/component/let)

> The current way of binding an observable to the view looks like that: `*ngIf="observableNumber$ | async as n"`. The problem is `*ngIf` is also interfering with rendering and in case of a falsy value the component would be hidden.
> The `*ngrxLet` directive takes over several things while making it more convenient and safe to work with streams in the template.

An explanatory tutorial about ngrxLet can be found [here](https://blog.angulartraining.com/ngrxlet-a-better-version-of-the-async-pipe-37bfc5c7a5ec).