# Angular Template: How to bind RXJS Observable and use its properties from a deeper nested object?

Tags: angular, templates, asynchronous, rxjs, observable

We have a clear solution from here [Angular Template: How to bind RXJS Observable and read its properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37672052/angular-template-how-to-bind-rxjs-observable-and-read-its-properties)

```
  <ng-container *ngIf="( game$ | async ) as game">
    <h3>{{ game.name }}</h3>
    <h3>{{ game.description }}</h3>
  </ng-container>
```

However, in case if we need a 0th player of a 0th command from the example above as a property from a deeper nested object, should we do it this way

```
  <ng-container *ngIf="( game$ | async )?.command?.[0]?.players?.[0] as player">
    <h3>{{ player.name }}</h3>
    <h3>{{ player.description }}</h3>
  </ng-container>
```

or there is a better way?

Answer (score 2):

You can use some so "bizarro" as

```
<ng-container *ngIf="( game$ | async ) as game">
    <h3>{{ game.name }}</h3>
    ------------------------
    <h3>{{ game.command?.[0]?.players?.[0].name }}</h3>
    <h3>{{ game.command?.[0]?.players?.[0].description }}</h3>
</ng-container>
```

Or create a temporaly variable using [*ngIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#storing-a-conditional-result-in-a-variable)

```
<ng-container *ngIf="( game$ | async ) as game">
    <h3>{{ game.name }}</h3>
    ------------------------
    <ng-container *ngIf="game.command?.[0]?.players.[0] 
                         || {name:'',description:''} as player">
    <h3>{{ player.name }}</h3>
    <h3>{{ player.description }}</h3>
</ng-container>
```

Or create a new Observable based in game$ using map

```
players$=this.game$.pipe(
   map(x=>x.command?.[0]?.players?.[0])
))
```